# Декодинг json ответа

Tags: json, golang

Собственно есть некое публичное апи, которое на определённый пост запрос даёт определённый ответ.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: kittenx
Date: Thu, 29 Oct 2020 11:25:00 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 643
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: KPHP/7.4.104570
Set-Cookie: remixir=DELETED; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.vk.com; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: remixstid=757990756_2f4LKqvz2JxYq0cgE5g3pwlhqjzsiCZBsmza6x3opBc; expires=Wed, 20 Oct 2021 22:44:51 GMT; path=/; domain=.vk.com; secure
Cache-control: no-store
Content-Encoding: gzip
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000

�������u�K��0����d�H`o6�<6�`^�l  ,����T��ͩ�*�<#͌���T��i:�.��wE�����8���*����$С�Z��5��Zi��jPK��Z�
��2-�l*��!�ʛ"���KN��+�)�I~OByW
��i�o�,��'9�d�rv�+m�jF(��J1(=���Λ��}��Q�w�!w�ˣ<�;��q�9F[,�;=Lg���Mi�=Y��i�ӏ�hM�#�E��a���������2�h!�׷��:��
���nl�e[&i��\z�N.'���t2~tw��'�m�`v��(�K�]>ً8�"��n�a�[�l�P����=/�6�1�Y�����G�;v�\��   [���L��Qx���5l����a�=���P���cavB�n-d��1Nb8pg,��@��g�&�t�P���-���c�g1��2���T��?���a�ڮv�kB�9�0Q�<�S��tVx�+�M�ODf鲏�;ʆ,OX�q��(d_>�"��!�N�e�-p�5܉%]�!�5�w'�Q����au��[�XǗ��z����KwcRAF7���~{A��2��xrG��'����2�g��o��:0����/�pBOD��
```

Этот же ответ фиддлер с включённым режимом json читает весьма корректно [ссылка на скрин](https://sun9-12.userapi.com/impf/vVNjpHnAWFDkJQ7XFzSkGF8GaYxiISCDC5lC7A/439TE4czqvw.jpg?size=1366x768&quality=96&proxy=1&sign=87d57343eb0b5bd9a0d471b1a2e54ff3)

Вопрос по сути прост: как при помощи гоу получить такой же json и декодировать его в структуру?

(Обычный текст с json декодируется спокойно, а вот тут видимо с кодировкой что-то, но не могу понять что)

Comment: Тут `Content-Encoding: gzip`

Comment: Попробуйте запретить сжатие в конструкторе транспорта: `http.Transport{ ...  DisableCompression: true, ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моём случае решением стало

```
responseBody := []byte{}
if response.Header.Get("Content-Encoding") == "gzip" {
    gr, err := gzip.NewReader(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        println(err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    responseBody, err = ioutil.ReadAll(gr)
    if err != nil {
        println(err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    gr.Close()
} else {
    responseBody, err = ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        println(err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }
}
```

(То есть декодирование gzip)